# Error creating hive table: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a multi node hadoop cluster and now I installed hive on the namenode.

Im trying to create some hive tables from files stored in hdfs but Im getting this strange error:

```
 FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from     
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. 
MetaException(message:hdfs://namenode-VirtualBox:9000/data/posts
/posts.tbl is not a directory or unable to create one)
    hive>
```

But, then I tried to create a table from a file stored in hdfs with only 2kb and the table was created with success.

But when I try to create a table from a file stored in hdfs larger like 200mb, and maybe less, I got that error.

Do you know why this error can be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe somwhere in the code the url: hdfs://namenode-VirtualBox:9000/data/posts
/posts.tbl
is parsed and the url should not have the file suffix (.tbl) should just be ".../posts"

I refer you to: [Unable to Create Table in HIVE reading a CSV from HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989187/unable-to-create-table-in-hive-reading-a-csv-from-hdfs)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution fix the issue. Its just strange because for tables with small size works with ".tbl".